# Terminology involved in C++ move

Tags: c++, move

On this page http://herbsutter.com/elements-of-modern-c-style/ in the "Move / &&" section it refers to the term *callee-allocated out* in the following context (quoted from that link):

```
// C++11: move
vector<int> make_big_vector(); // usually sufficient for 'callee-allocated out' situations
:::
auto result = make_big_vector(); // guaranteed not to copy the vector
```

What does that term mean?

Comment: Do you know what a "caller-allocated" buffer is?  The *callee* is the function that the caller calls.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Callee-allocated" as in allocated by the function being called, "out" meaning data being returned.  This is as opposed to "caller-allocated" where the caller would have to pass the allocated structure into the function.